# What is the difference between an IBOutlet and an IBOutlet property?

Tags: xcode, iboutlet

I've noticed while connecting an outlet that if I place the code outside of the brackets it makes the outlet into a property. How does it behave differently than a regular IBOutlet?

[image]

Comment: Search before asking, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "regular IBOutlet". `IBOutlet` is just an internal keyword giving Xcode a hint that it should allow the making of an outlet by this name in Interface Builder. What you're describing really has nothing to do with the `IBOutlet` keyword at all. It's just the ordinary difference between an instance variable declaration and a property declaration.

- An instance variable is an instance-level variable.
- An accessor method is a method for getting or setting an instance variable.
- A property is shorthand for calling / declaring accessor methods (and with synthesis, the declaration is shorthand for generating the accessor methods).

And [see my book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_properties_2) for endless details...!